# Scanning multiple choices answers from paper

Tags: image-processing, ocr, data, scanning

I want to create a form that asks:

```
How much do you agree with the following sentences:

"Policy X is good"  
Disagree - Agree  
{Box1} {Box2} {Box3} {Box4} {Box5}

"Policy Y is good"  
Disagree - Agree  
{Box1} {Box2} {Box3} {Box4} {Box5}

"Policy Z is good"  
Disagree - Agree  
{Box1} {Box2} {Box3} {Box4} {Box5}
```

I want to hand those forms out as paper.
I don't want to manually transfer the results from the paper to my computer but put all the papers in a scanner who checks which boxes are ticked.

Is there a software that facilitates this process?

Comment: This is a very good question. I formatted it a bit and added some more tags. BTW, which platform should your software run on? Or could you also use a web service for that?

Comment: What about price? And once the results are scanned back in, what do you want to with them: counts, user management, etc? What about question types: only single-answer questions? How should the software handle unanswered questions. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interesting in creating an application that can do this, I reccomend checking out the [LEADTOOLS Forms Recognition SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/forms). This SDK has C DLL and .NET libraries for OMR recognition. The .NET interface includes a forms recognition and processing library for defining a form such as this and processing it. The SDK includes scanning support as well as image processing to correct for skewing and image cleanup. This SDK could be used for developing an application that could automatically grade tests in this type of format or process opinion questionaires as you seem to have.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of the company that wrote this library.